# elements ignored google maps KML

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a georeferencing tool that ouputs google earth KMZ files from JPG files (mapc2mapc)
It breaks my map up into 100 tiles and saves it as a GE KMZ
It loads perfectly into Google earth.
I then output from GE and save as a KML.

When I open the KML in Google maps it says "110 elements ignored proceed?"
There is no sign of the tiles when I look in their expected location on the map.
The KMZ is 20 MB in size.
Both the KML and associated tiles are all in the same directory?

I was building my map site around google earth API but as it is a lot of work and google are dumping it next December I see no point in persuing it in GE.

Any help would be appreciated.. Thank you

Comment: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/mapsSupport

Answer (score 0):

My question is answered from the link above. Relevant info below. Thank you

Maximum fetched file size (raw KML, raw GeoRSS, or compressed KMZ)  3MB

Maximum uncompressed KML file size  10MB

Maximum number of Network Links     10

Maximum number of total document-wide features  1,000